# Is "I hope I was of good help" idiomatic in English?

Tags: grammar, american-english

I was talking to a friend and I wanted to say something like:

> "I hope I was of (good/any) help."

The phrase "be of help" is used in expressions like "How can I be of help?"  Can the word "help" be modified with an adjective like "good" in this expression?

Comment: Hello Rosieeeee and welcome to ELL! Unfortunately, questions asking whether something is correct is considered "proofreading", and is off-topic for this site. Please check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for other ways to improve your question

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't say "I hope I was of (good/any) help."

"good help" isn't idiomatic here.

"any help" may be used in a questions and conditionals such as "if that was any help..." or "was that of any help?"

Valid options are:

I hope that helped [you].
I hope I was able to help [you].
I hope I was of [at least] some help [in this matter].

The phrase "at least some help" has a similar meaning to "any help", and you may use that as a substitute.

If you really wanted to emphasis "*good* help", well, it's not recommended. Such sentences are "I hope this has been very helpful to you" or even "I trust this has been of great aid in your endeavor", however it sounds presumptuous to assume your help was overly valuable.